# Setting drawer to lock mode is also disabling the hamburger icon

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to disable the left swipe gesture for opening the navigation drawer  as its messing with my seekbar. But setting drawer to LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED is also disabling my hamburger icon.

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);    
drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
            drawerToggle.syncState();
            drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. They recently changed the behavior of `ActionBarDrawerToggle` to disable opening/closing the drawer if it's locked. Are you setting the `Toolbar` as the support `ActionBar`?

Comment: yes, I'm setting Toolbar as my actionBar.

Comment: OK. I've got a workaround for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. They recently changed the behavior of `ActionBarDrawerToggle` to disable opening/closing the drawer if it's locked.

Since your `Toolbar` is the support `ActionBar`, a workaround is to remove the `Toolbar` argument from the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` constructor call. This will cause the `Activity`'s `onOptionsItemSelected()` method to be called upon clicking the toggle, and there you can check the `MenuItem`'s item ID, and unlock the drawer before calling the toggle's method.

The `ActionBarDrawerToggle` class works a little differently with an `ActionBar` than a `Toolbar`, so you'll need to add the following call to show the toggle.

```
getSupportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Then change your `ActionBarDrawerToggle` constructor call as follows:

```
drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
                                         drawer,
                                         R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                                         R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
    }
};
```

And override the `Activity`'s `onOptionsItemSelected()` method like so:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
        drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        return true;
    }
    ...

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: After doing this I'm not seeing my hamburger icon anymore. Any idea?

Comment: Oh, whoops! Yeah, you also need to call `getSupportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`. I forgot that part. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!! One more thing though, you'll also have to keep the drawer in lock mode by default, otherwise it won't work until you've open the drawer at least once.

Comment: I don't follow ya. Whadya mean?

Comment: I was able to open drawer by left swiping when I opened the app. Then when I closed once, then only it disabled the left swipe gesture. So, I had to use drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED); to keep it closed by default. I thought this line was not needed anymore.

Comment: Oh, no, sorry, I meant you had to change just the constructor call. Everything else stays the same. Glad you got it worked out, though. Cheers!

Comment: I get null for setting `getSupportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`. Any ideas why?

Comment: @DanielReyhanian Sounds like you've got a `NoActionBar` theme on the `Activity` – or an equivalent theme that removes the default `ActionBar` – and you've not called `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` with a non-null `Toolbar` before that `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` call.

Comment: I didn't expect you to answer that fast after 3 years! Damn it you are so good. My theme is set to `Theme = "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"`. What shall I do?

Comment: I have set it to `Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"` and now the burger icon appears yet it doesn't open any drawer. (Looking gooooood btw)

Comment: @DanielReyhanian Um, hmm, did you remember to override the `Activity`'s `onOptionsItemSelected()` method? If so, is it getting called at all? Do you see any visual feedback when you click the toggle icon?

Comment: I did override it but the app crashes when I choose from it. Is there any way to set a listener for the burger icon? That will solve everything. I want to unlock the drawer whenever it is pressed..

Comment: Btw, I successfully set a listener for the toolbar itself but I can't set it to the burger button.

Comment: @DanielReyhanian Well, when you're using the default `ActionBar`, that pretty much is the listener for that button. If you were to provide your own `Toolbar`, you could call `setNavigationOnClickListener()` on that to handle that click. Might be easier to diagnose the crash.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're at, now, as far as what your current setup is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192688/discussion-between-daniel-reyhanian-and-mike-m).